# Only displaying one item from Array

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, arrays

With the following code, when you click on a hyperlink, it loads array items into the brand-content div.  When you click the Nike hyperlink for example, it only loads item 3 from the array and the items 1 and 2 are missing?

```
 <?php
 $brand = array (
 "nike" => array (
            array('logo'=>'images/nike.png', 'description' =>'some nike text1'),
            array('logo'=>'images/nike.png', 'description' =>'some nike text2'),
            array('logo'=>'images/nike.png', 'description' =>'some nike text3')),
 "puma" => array(
            array('logo'=>'images/puma.png', 'description' =>'some puma text'),
            array('logo'=>'images/puma.png', 'description' =>'some puma text'),
            array('logo'=>'images/puma.png', 'description' =>'some puma text')),
 "addidas" => array(
            array('logo'=>'images/addidas.png', 'description'=>'some addidas text1'),
            array('logo'=>'images/addidas.png', 'description'=>'some addidas text2'),
            array('logo'=>'images/addidas.png', 'description'=>'some addidas text3')),
 "Asics" => array(
            array('logo'=>'images/Asics.png', 'description'=>'some Asics text'),
            array('logo'=>'images/Asics.png', 'description'=>'some Asics text'),
            array('logo'=>'images/Asics.png', 'description'=>'some Asics text')),
 "Qicksilver" => array(
            array('logo'=>'images/Qicksilver.png', 'description'=>'some Qicksilver text'),
            array('logo'=>'images/Qicksilver.png', 'description'=>'some Qicksilver text'),
            array('logo'=>'images/Qicksilver.png', 'description'=>'some Qicksilver text')),
  );
  ?>

<style type="text/css">
    a {
        margin-left: 10px;
    }
    #brand-content {
        margin-top: 50px;
        border: solid 1px #000;
        padding: 10px;
        display: none;
        width: 50%;
    }
    #brand-content img {
        margin-right: 25px;
    }

</style>

<script>var brand =<?php echo json_encode($brand) ?>;// json_encode($brand) is equivalent to the following:      {"nike":[{"logo":"images\/nike.png","description":"some nike text"},     {"logo":"images\/nike.png","description":"some nike text"},{"logo":"images\/nike.png","description":"some nike text"}],"puma":[{"logo":"images\/puma.png","description":"some puma text"},  {"logo":"images\/puma.png","description":"some puma text"},{"logo":"images\/puma.png","description":"some puma text"}],"addidas":[{"logo":"images\/addidas.png","description":"some addidas text"},{"logo":"images\/addidas.png","description":"some addidas text"},{"logo":"images\/addidas.png","description":"some addidas text"}],"Asics":[{"logo":"images\/Asics.png","description":"some Asics text"},{"logo":"images\/Asics.png","description":"some Asics text"},{"logo":"images\/Asics.png","description":"some Asics text"}],"Qicksilver":[{"logo":"images\/Qicksilver.png","description":"some Qicksilver text"},{"logo":"images\/Qicksilver.png","description":"some Qicksilver text"},  {"logo":"images\/Qicksilver.png","description":"some Qicksilver text"}]}

    function readyLinks() {
        for (var n in brand) {
            for (var i in brand[n]) {
                var link = document.createElement("a");
                link.href = brand[n][i].logo;
                link.innerHTML = n;
                link.setAttribute("data-description", brand[n][i].description);
                link.onclick = function() {
                    document.getElementById("brand-content").innerHTML = "<img src=\"" + this.href + "\"/>" + this.getAttribute("data-description");
                    document.getElementById("brand-content").style.display = "block";
                    return false;
                }
            }
            document.getElementById("brand-nav").appendChild(link);
        }
    }


    window.onload = function() {
        readyLinks();
    }

</script>

<!-- body -->

<div id="brand-nav"></div>

<div id="brand-content"></div>
```

The actual array that I will be using will be like the following:

```
  "Nike" => array( 
        array('id'=>'01','logo'=>'images/nike-logo.jpg', 'productTitle' => "Nike Air   Max",'productImage' => "images/airmax.jpg",'productDescription' => "Nike Air Max are awesome ",'rrp' => "RRP £100.00",'salePrice' => "Now ONLY £80.00"), 

  array('id'=>'02','logo'=>'images/nike-logo.jpg', 'productTitle' => "Nike Plus Running Shoes",'productImage' => "images/plus.jpg",'productDescription' => "Nike plus are even more awesome ",'rrp'  => "RRP £120.00",'salePrice' => "Now ONLY £90.00"),
```

So do I need to add additional getAttributes for the additional fields in the array for everything to display?

```
this.getAttribute("id");
this.getAttribute("productTitle");
this.getAttribute("productDescription");
```

Volterony

Comment: Hi. Could you explain what your actual question is here? Please explain what you want to do, what you have tried, the result you get, and the result you want. Please also see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Essentially I want to display all the items from the SECOND example Nike array into the brand-content div.  (This is the actual array I will be working with)  The smaller array is a test.  At the moment only the 3rd item is getting pulled in?  1 and 2 are missing??

Comment: im missing your DOM append statements in the readyLinks function, how do you do that?

Comment: move appendChild one braket above in the for (i....) operation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function readyLinks()
 {
 for (var n in brand){
 for (var i in brand[n]){
 var link = document.createElement("a");
 link.href = brand[n][i].logo;
 link.innerHTML = n;
 link.setAttribute("data-description",brand[n][i].description);

 link.onclick = function(){
 document.getElementById("brand-content").innerHTML = "<img src=\""+this.href+"\"/>" +  this.getAttribute("data-description");
 document.getElementById("brand-content").style.display = "block";
 return false;}
 document.getElementById("brand-nav").appendChild(link);
 }}}
```

Comment: Moving document.getElementById("brand-nav").appendChild(link); into the link.onclick function doesn't work.  Nothing loads on page load!

Comment: sorry a little copy and paste mistake ;----) changed that

Comment: Thorsten, thanks for taking the time to play with this.  I've tried out your answer but what is happening with yours is that each brand now has 3 hyperlinks!!  Essentially It is meant to behave like the original one I posted.  Each brand will have ONE hyperlink, and onclick will load its array elements into brand-content div.

Comment: In php, I looped through the brands with foreach $brand as $k => $v.  $k was the brand array and $v was the array of items.  Then to display each array item from each brand, I did foreach ($v as $key => $val).  So I am thinking that in the link.onclick function, I need to iterate through each array item?

Comment: Absolutely Awesome Thorsten!!!  So say I want to work with this array format array('id'=>'01','logo'=>'images/nike-logo.jpg', 'productTitle' => "Nike Air   Max",'productImage' => "images/airmax.jpg",'productDescription' => "Nike Air Max are awesome ",'rrp' => "RRP £100.00",'salePrice' => "Now ONLY £80.00"),  would I just add the additional fields to : document.getElementById("brand-content").innerHTML = "<img src=\""+this.href+"\"/>" +  this.getAttribute("data-description");

Comment: i dont know exactly what you mean. explain!  what you have is brand(object)->companies (object) -> array of objects->item (object) with Properties logo and description...what should brand extended look like

Comment: item object would have additional properties: productTitle, productImage, RRP, and Salesprice

Comment: then you can get them in my onclick function with item.productTitle, item.productImage,   after the line item=LogoDescription_Arr.. what i do is appendind your Description Arr to the link HTML_Element, you created with document.createElement, so the HTML Element has a property called LogoDescription_Arr which is an Array, like it has a property called src which is an string , you can call it with linkID.LogoDescription_Arr each link has his own array.  thats what i do, and what do you want?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47509/discussion-between-volterony-and-thorsten-artner-austria)

Answer (score 0):

```
function readyLinks()
  {
  var company, link;
  for (company in brand)
    {
    link = document.createElement("a");
    link.innerHTML = company;
    link.LogoDescription_Arr=brand[company];
    link.onclick = function()
      {
      var container=document.getElementById("brand-content"); 
      var LogoDescription_Arr=this.LogoDescription_Arr, i, l =LogoDescription_Arr.length, item;
      var outPutHTML="";          
      for (i=0;i<l;i++)
        {
        item=LogoDescription_Arr[i];
        outPutHTML+= "<img src=\""+item.logo+"\"/>" +  item.description;
        }
      container.innerHTML=outPutHTML;          
      container.style.display = "block";
      return false;
      }
    document.getElementById("brand-nav").appendChild(link);
    }
  }
```

Comment: if that isnt what you search for, i'll gave up. I appologize because of languages misunderstanding. I'm from Austria and  sometimes English is hard to understand.